# Switch between SharePoint sites pointing to different servers

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, iis

I have two SharePoint sites with PPS reports on it. They both are identical but pointing to different server (i.e. the data in those sites are different).

Lets say site 1 url is `Site1.KT.com/Some_app/` and other site (site 2) is hosted localy on the same server (its url is servername:8787/Some_app/). Now my requirement is to switch user between the site.

User will type `Site1.KT.com/Some_app/` in the browser and will see the site pointing to one server. Now, for some time I want to replace site 1 with site 2. So, user will now see Site 2 (local site) while using URL `Site1.KT.com/Some_app/` (i.e. site 1 URL).

Basically, I want to switch betwen two sites without in the easiest way so the URL will be same. As this switch should happen programatically (i.e. no manual intervention or update to IIS) and I have no understanding about SharePoint so below are my 2 cents approach:

- Is it possible to change the site attribute of site2 as same as site1? with that I mean, I give the same port and URL binding to site2 and make site1 down.
- Is it possible to create redirect user from Site1 to site2 disguising that site 2 has the same URL?

*I have tried to copy site content from site2 folder (inetpub/wwwroot/wss/site2) to site1 folder. I thought just like ASP.NET webform application it will show site2 now but that didn't work. I am shocked to see that even after pasting site2 content in site1 virtual directory, site1 URL is showing site1 only*

Is there any better way to handle this requirement?